# Google Cloud Storage - getting public URL without knowing specific filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails `5.2.3` app being hosted on Google Cloud services. On my frontend, I require users to upload images of their employees, and these images get saved into a GC Storage bucket, and importantly for my question, they're saved with **randomized names**. There's hundreds of these images, and they all have what basically amounts to random 40+ character strings as names inside the buckets.

In the DB, each User has multiple Employees, and each Employee has one image attached.

I'm trying to create an Email in which I need to include an image of one specific employee for each user. Right now, I'm using the `ActiveStorage::service_url` method, but the problem is that the `service_url` method will return a [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) from GCS, which has a (by default) 5 minute TTL, meaning the image will stop being accessible after 5 minutes and users get a broken image. The image *does* actually show up fine initially, it just expires after 5 minutes.

An example of how I'm using the `service_url` method in my mailer view

```
<%= image_tag (employee.photo.service_url) if employee.photo.attached? %>
```

Now, the GCS docs state that to get the public URL, you just have to use the `BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME` URL, but because there's hundreds of these files and they're saved with randomized names (I'm not the one that set that up initially, don't ask why), I simply don't have a way of doing that in a sensible way for each user, especially since this is a weekly email that goes out to each and every user denoting their staff members that are performing the best, so even for one client the email will use a different picture from week to week.

Is there any way for me to get the public image URL for use in these emails?

My `storage.yml` file

```yaml
google:
  service: GCS
  project: REDACTED
  credentials: <%= Rails.application.credentials.gcs_storage_credentials.to_json %>
  bucket: images-REDACTED
```

My `production.rb` env file

```rb
config.active_storage.service = :google
config.action_mailer.asset_host = Rails.application.credentials.send(production_server_url)
```

My Gemfile

```rb
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'active_storage_base64'
gem 'google-cloud-storage', '~> 1.8', require: false
```

Comment: Did you check out https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-url?

Comment: @max Unfortunately, I'm on Rails 5.2.3 which doesn't support the `Blob::url` method (unless I'm wrong, calling `employee.photo.url` returns a `undefined method` error)

Comment: `service_url` should have the signature so you should be able to use `service_url(expires_in: 1.year.to_i)`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-service_url

Comment: @max Beautiful, that worked! Seems a bit hacky though, is there any drawback to going that route? 

You should probably post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: I can't think of anything in particular off the top of my head. On a side note you should not put spaces between the method name and parens as in `image_tag (employee.photo.service_url)`. Since parens are optional in ruby its actually evaluated as `image_tag((employee.photo.service_url))` - and if you add an additional argument you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While max's answer is a good one should you have a need for your assets eventually expiring, I needed a more permanent solution. Turns out it was really simple, I simple had to call `employee.photo` and GCS seems to be spitting out a permanent URL!

Answer (score 1):

You can [set the expiry per URL](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-service_url):

```
image_tag(employee.photo.service_url(expires_in: 1.year.to_i))
```